# Name multiple variables using STDIN

Tags: perl, stdin

I'm trying to use  to read in user input to a programme as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; 

if ($#ARGV == 0) { 
print "What condition are you sorting?\t";
chomp(my $condition = <STDIN>);

# Use $condition in further blocks of code...

}
```

This is working. However When I can't work out how to enter 2 (or more) values to be used in a similar fashion. E.g

```
if ($#ARGV == 1) {  
print "What conditions are you comparing?\t";
chomp(my $condition1 = <STDIN>);
chomp(my $condition2 = <STDIN>);
```

Allows me to input twice, but the formatting is distorted:

```
What conditions are you comparing?  <condition1>
<condition2>
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter conditions separated by comma or white space to preserve formatting,

```
chomp(my $input = <STDIN>);

my ($condition1, $condition2) = split /[\s,]+/, $input;
```